# ¿Cómo pongo etiqueta aside en la esquina superior izquierda?

Tags: html, css, posicionamiento

No sé si alguien habrá preguntado esto ya antes... pero quiero que aside se ponga en la es quina superior izquierda, y no la doy movido. Siempre se queda por debajo de el párrafo que escribí. Ya ni sé que hacer.
[image: Aquí a lo que me refiero, tapé la imagen y el párrafo.]

Código CSS:

```
html{
    background-image:url(images/m2.gif);
    margin:3in;
    margin-top:0.3in;
}
aside{
    background-image:url(images/negrofondo.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    width:2in;
    height:6in;
}
body{
    background-image:url(images/negrofondo.jpg);
}
p{
    text-align:center;
    color:silver;
}
```

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>El sitio de REBEL</title>
        <link rel="shorcut icon" href="images/sitiofav.ico">
        <link style="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="reb_uber.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/reblvdka.gif" hspace="445">
            <main>
                <p>[TEXTO] </p>
            </main>
        <aside>
            <img src="images/enlaces.png">
        </aside>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque podría solucionarse con más códigos de una mejor manera, te muestro la forma más fácil usando `float` y algunos retoques para que sea responsivo

```css
            
* {
box-sizing: border-box
}

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden
}

html { 
background-image:url(images/m2.gif);  
} 

body {  
background-image:url(images/negrofondo.jpg); 
}

main {
float: right;
width: calc(100% - 2in); /* ancho total menos ancho del aside */  
background: rgba(0,128,0, 0.3)
}

aside { 
float: left;
background: rgba(255,0,0, 0.3) url(images/negrofondo.jpg); 
background-repeat:repeat-y;
width:2in; 
height:6in;
} 

aside img {
display: block;
width: 100%
}

p{ 
text-align:center; 
color:silver; 
}
```

```html
            
<main> 
        
    <p>[TEXTO] </p> 
        
</main> 
    
<aside>
        
    <img src="images/enlaces.png"> 
        
</aside>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias usuario, he de intentarlo comprender por mi mismo y aprender, soy de esas personas que tiene idea de html/css pero a la vez no jaja. En un caso extremo ya copiaría y pegaría el código. Gracias :-)